# Tailwind doesn't apply style

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Tailwind doesn't apply style on my file but it works in page.tsx, I'm using NextJS with Tailwind.

I have created a commponent Menu.tsx declared as :

```
export default function Menu() {
  return <div className="bg-red" >
    <div className="text-red">
      Create Todo
    </div>
    <div>
      Favorites
    </div>
  </div >
}
```

`tailwind.config.ts`

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config
```

`postcss.config.js`

```
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

`next.config.js`

```
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

my global.css contains

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

and layout.css

```
import './globals.css'
```

[project architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSxXr.png)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`bg-red` and `text-red` are not valid on current versions of Tailwind. Try `text-red-500` and `bg-red-500` instead. All colors with the exception of white and black appear to have to have a number after (50, 100, 200,...,950) the color name unless you have specifically configured them yourself.